# Is there a CMS (WYSIWYG) Component for Agile Toolkit?

Tags: php, frameworks, content-management-system, wysiwyg, atk4

I haven't seen the code in the standard distribution of Agile Toolkit. Does anyone have a add-on code which integrates Agile Toolkit form with some WYSIWYG editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It have been half year since the question was asked and now there is a dedicated add-on for Agile Toolkit called "CMS". The component is based on "elRTE"

Screencast
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5dmAnvri1I&feature=plcp

Sources:
https://github.com/atk4/ambient-addons

Answer (score 1):

any jQuery based editor would fit best. last one we played around with was ELRTE and it was very easy to get it up and running.

Comment: elRTE is available at http://sourceforge.net/projects/elrte/files/ Other jQuery based WYSIWYG editors are: [HtmlBox](http://remiya.com/htmlbox/), [Xinha](http://trac.xinha.org/), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/), [Tiny MCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/), [FCK](http://drupal.org/project/fckeditor)  [Rick Text Editor](http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/posts/2007-09-11-1/rich-text-editor-jquery.html)

Comment: that's true, but Agile Toolkit makes developers very lazy, so I am waiting for a ready-to-use code which i can activate with few lines of code. Thanks for great compilation of editors though.

Comment: $f->getElement('content')
            ->js(true)->_load('elrte.min')
            ->alrte(array('width'=>637,'height'=>300,'cssfiles'=>array('templates/jui/css/general.css','templates/jui/css/elrte_tab.css'))); -- pretty much all you need to enable rte ;)

Answer (score 0):

With this we can add a field richtext maybe?! Don't forget the all mighty TinyMCE and FCKEditor

Comment: Certainly, but would rather see a form field which i can use with one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have got this code from other developer:

```
$url=$this->api->locateURL('js','wymeditor/jquery.wymeditor.js');
$this->api->template->append('js_include', '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.
     $url.'"></script>'."\n");


$form->getElement('description')
    ->js(true)
    ->wymeditor(
        array(
            'updateEvent' => 'mouseenter',
            'updateSelector' => '.ui-button',
    ));
```