# Implementing a WYSIWYG Editor for ATK4

Tags: atk4

In reference to this question [Is there a CMS (WYSIWYG) Component for Agile Toolkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810092/is-there-a-wysiwyg-component-for-agile-toolkit-forms), I am trying to add the elRTE editor as a default RTE for my install of ATK4.

Simply, where should I put the elRTE files within the atk4 directory structure?

TIA
PG

Additional info:

Has anybody managed to get a WYSIWYG editor working?

I have tried with tinyMCE and elRTE.  I have placed both libraries in the atk4/templates/js folder and then loaded via my Admin api class (I want the libraries available to all my Admin models):

```
 $this->js()
        ->_load('atk4_univ')
        ->_load('ui.atk4_notify')
        ->_load('tiny_mce/tiny_mce')
        ;
```

if I'm trying elRTE then I load that and not tinyMCE -

```
            ->_load('elrte/js/elrte.min')
```

then in my page_manager class I try and instantiate the wysiwyg editor:

```
$tabs=$this->add('Tabs');
$crud = $tabs->addTab('listing')->add('CRUD');
$crud->setModel('Listing',array('title','body'),array('title'));

if ($crud->form) {
    $f = $crud->form;
    $f->getElement('body')->js(true)->tinyMCE.init();
}
```

I have tried various different permutations depending on the library I am trying to call and nothing works - I either just get an empty form for editing or it just sites there displaying a loading message. Below are the some of the different variations that I have tried:

```
$f->getElement('body')->js(true,'tinyMCE.init(mode:"textareas")');

$f->getElement('body')->js(true,'elrte()');

$f->getElement('body')->js(true)->elrte();
```

At my wits end, all I want is a simple wysiwyg editor on the admin CRUD

Comment: Please expand upon your question by using the 'edit' button rather than adding edits as an answer.  Good luck!

Comment: Have done so - sorry, just finding my feet at this site.

Answer (score 0):

I cant give direct answer but a suggestion:

Normally you should put js under templates/js/elrte/ and use PathFinder. I've integrated StackOverflow's Markdown UI like this:

```
$m=$f->getElement('text');
$m->js(true)->parent()->prepend('<div id="'.$m->name.'-bar"></div>');
$m->js(true)->parent()->append('<div id="'.$m->name.'-preview" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>');
$m->js(true,' var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter(); var editor1 = new Markdown.Editor(converter1,"'.
        $m->name.'");editor1.run();');

$this->api->jquery->addStaticInclude('pagedown/Markdown.Converter');
$this->api->jquery->addStaticInclude('pagedown/Markdown.Sanitizer');
$this->api->jquery->addStaticInclude('pagedown/Markdown.Editor');
$this->api->template->append('js_include',
    '<link type="text/css" href="'.$this->api->locateURL('js','pagedown/demo/browser/demo.css').'" rel="stylesheet" />'."\n");
```

I had to do a manual change for the JS file to support the ID fields with prefixes, but you can use a very similar approach for any editor. Paste your code here once you've done integrating.

Comment: in your code, don't use _load() but use addStaticInclude instead. Compare the source of the page produced by agile toolkit with the demo page.

Comment: I amended my code to use addStaticInclude - but it made no difference.